# Covariance between list of stock returns and market return

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a portfolio that has 20 stocks (equally weighted) and I'm computing a single index model with S&P500 as my market index. In order to find portfolio betas, I need covariance(stock, market)/variance(market). So I have evaluated the variance of the market and now when I'm trying to evaluate the covariance between the two I get the following problem:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here the code I've used:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tickers = ['KO', 'WMT', 'TSN', 'KMB', 'ADBE', 'AAPL', 'MCHP', 'MSFT', 'JPM', 'MCO', 'ETFC', 'TRV', 'CVX', 'DVN', 'MPC', 'OKE', 'ATVI', 'FB', 'NFLX', 'OMC']
n = len(tickers)
wts = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
start = '2019-04-01'
end = '2020-04-01'

stock_data = web.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start, end)
stock_data = stock_data['Adj Close']
stock_data = stock_data.resample('M').ffill()

market = '^GSPC'
market_data = web.get_data_yahoo(market, start, end)
market_data = market_data['Adj Close']
market_data = market_data.resample('M').ffill()

stock_return = np.log(stock_data/stock_data.shift(1))[1:]
market_return = np.log(market_data/market_data.shift(1))[1:]
market_variance = market_return.var()

covariance = stock_return.cov(market_return)
print(covariance)
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thank you!!

Comment: A nit: instead of your `[0.05, ... 0.05,]` you can have `[0.05] * n`

Comment: please post the full tracecback when asking for help.